# One button click per IP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ip

In my asp.net mvc application I need to allow only one click, or rather calculation triggered by the button click only once per IP. E.g : Each user can vote only once. Is it possible to do this with C#? Where is a right place to start please ? Let me know if I need to rephrase the question.Thanks!

Comment: You know that a **lot** more than one user might share a single IP?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, true. What would you suggest in this case ?

Comment: Register the vote against the user and disable voting further so that he won't vote again on the same. (else most things here on SO would hv upvoted n times :) )

Comment: @V4Vendetta, you mean that each voter has to be registered ? What if I would like unregistered users to vote ? I guess that would be impossible ?

Comment: Do you really want to provide anonymous voting then m not sure if the voting is any good at all, the SO team is also dealing with such a thing and their first cut was introducing the *Was this post useful-- Yes/No* but still thinking of how to relate this data, maybe someone from SO team could highlight as they would hv met all types of hurdles

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to do this, that I have done with my app.

First IP address is a good way, though not 100% as many people can share a single IP address and also people can restart their connections and get a new IP address. So storing voters IP addresses in the database is a good start.

Second you can use cookies. That again isn't a 100% secure approach as people can delete them. However you can use this in conjuction with IP address.

Third if you have a Facebook app, this is where you can get the best security. You just check the Facebook UserId. You can do this if you make your voters login with Facebook as well, even if your app isnt a custom Facebook app on a page tab.

So for coding sakes you need a database to store these values and check against when viewing. However in a high traffic site it lends itself to being very DB heavy, so some caching is also a good start (if you are on shared grid/webfarm hosting make sure your cache is not inprocess)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Totally agreed with [Joel Coehoom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn).

I would suggest to use MAC address in this case.

For help about this try these following links:

[PhysicalAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.aspx)

[Get MAC address of client machine using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/1344dad4-dffe-486c-bf30-1b75d21fc9ba/)

Comment: Is it possible to get a client's MAC Address through a web application ?

Comment: not impossible.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888907/web-server-to-fetch-clients-machine-mac-address