# is it possible to get MAC Address and Signal Strength of Available Access points using HTML5?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, geolocation

while understanding HTML5's GeoLocation, I found that browser shares user's IP address and details of nearby wireless networks with Google to determine his/her location.
where details of available access point contains: 
"mac_address", 
"signal_strength", 
"age" and 
"SSID"

is it possible to get these four information also from user's browser when he/she visits my website (which I am developing using C#) instead of just getting location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888907/web-server-to-fetch-clients-machine-mac-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to get that information.